# Can I run a WiFi router on a 12 V, 50 A lead-acid battery?

Tags: voltage, current, power-electronics, amperage

I have a router that takes 5 V, 0.3 A from the AC adapter.
I have a 12 V, 50 A lead-acid battery.

What if I reduce only the voltage to 5 V through any stepdown module; will it work?

And what are the parameters to know the maximum voltage/current for the device?

Comment: Could that be a 50 **Ah** battery instead of a 50 **A** battery? Anyway, stepping down to 5 V is enough; the router's impedance will decide what current is pulled. See link in winny's comment for details.

Comment: yeah, i read the link you mentioned above I think this is enough for my knowledge.